# Remove gaps between two polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have already found some ideas how to solve this problem but none of them seem to fit perfectly.

I need to remove the gaps between a shapefile and a Feature Class in our Database so that I can import the shapefile without topology differences. Here is an example:

[image]

The shapefile polygons are mostly parcels of the bigger one. The problem mainly occurs when there are curves. So I need to adjust that curved border without changing the upper border. And this for like 2000 polygons.

I found out about 3 possibilities:

1. **Snap tool** `->` wont change anything
2. **integrate tool** `->` looked pretty fine in the beginning but it also changes the inner borders
3. **trace tool** `->` tracing the borders manually is a way but before I start this with 2000 polygons I would like to ask my question here.

Comment: Since you have this in a geodatabase, you can use [Topology rules](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm) (Standard license required). There are a lot of them, so you can probably find one or a few in combination that fits.

Comment: I think the trace tool is the best way, though a lot of manual work. Maybe you could try an intersect of both layers and then look automatically to join the little pieces back to biggest neighbor polygon. But for make this proper work it will need some effort. So probably the manual work is in your case faster.

Comment: I thought of topology rules too but since the shapefile polygons are mostly only subareas of the bigger one, the topology will have many errors.

The insersect idea is probably a way but like you already mentioned it needs manual work too

Comment: I want to share how i finally solved this problem: First i clipped the features to eliminate the parts which where outside the borders of the other polygons. In the other direction the clip result gives back the gaps between the features and the border but not as a feature. So i used union with the property "no gaps allowed" to generate Features (FID = -1) for those gaps...which i finally merged in editing one by one.

Comment: I think you should answer your own question by posting an answer instead of posting an answer within a comment.  Self-answering is fine to do, and can pick you up some reputation towards unlocking site functionality.